# explode a pyspark column with root name intact

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe , schema looks like this:

```
|-- col1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- NM: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I explode col2 so that final column name looks like `col1, col2.NM` etc

Comment: can you post a small testable fragment of your dataframe?

Comment: You can use this data data = [
  ("2022-02-20 10:00:00", [("primary",), ("secondary",)]),
  ("2022-02-20 11:00:00", [("primary",), ("tertiary",)])
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2"]). so the colum name should be col1, col2._1

Comment: your initial schema with string attributes would be more convenient for testing

Comment: I have changed the initial schemabased on the input I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Since you have multiple such columns, you can create list of those columns and use the below:

```
cols_to_explode = ["col2","col3"]
other_cols = [F.col(c) for c in df.schema.names if c not in cols_to_explode]
struct_cols = list(chain(*[[F.col(col + "."+ c).alias(col+"_" + c) for c in df.withColumn(col, F.explode(col)).selectExpr(col+".*").columns] for col in df.schema.names if col in cols_to_explode]))

df \
.withColumn("asZipped", F.arrays_zip(*cols_to_explode))\
.withColumn("asZipped", F.explode("asZipped"))\
.select(other_cols+ [F.col("asZipped."+col).alias(col) for col in df.schema.names if col in cols_to_explode])\
.select(other_cols+struct_cols)\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

[image: Multi_col_input]

Output:

[image: Output]

---

This would work

```
df \
.withColumn("col2", F.explode("col2"))\
.select([F.col(c) for c in df.schema.names if c!="col2"]+[F.col("col2." + c).alias("col2_" + c) for c in df.withColumn("col2", F.explode("col2")).selectExpr("col2.*").columns])\
.show()
```

Input DF:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: like col2 I have col3,col4 as well.will it work?

Comment: @ista120 Updated answer for multiple such columns, let me know if you face any issue

Comment: with the updated answers, I am still having array type columns.

Comment: @ista120 can you try now, I've update the output as well

Comment: it's working..Thanks. I nned some help regarding spark memory numbers.could you please check this one?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75526751/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-trying-write-data-into-postgressql-database