# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while trying write data into postgressql database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using AWS Glue G 2X- 3 worker nodes, each 8 vcpu, 32 gb ram, input data size 16 gb approx in parquet format

I have almost 300 parquet files in s3, which I want to read at one shot by passing /*.parquet, create a dataframe, do some operation and finally storing into postgress db. Below pyspark code I have written:

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load('s3_path/* parquet')
df = df.withColumn("providers", F.explode("providers")) \
        .select(
        [F.col(c) for c in df.schema.names if c != "providers"] + [
            F.col("providers." + c).alias("providers." + c) for c in
            df.withColumn("providers",
                          F.explode("providers")).selectExpr(
                "providers.*").columns])
# Similar operayion for 3 other columns

df = df.withColumn("rt_no", lit(rt_no)) \
           .withColumn("table_name", lit(table_name))
df = df.withColumn("json_content", to_json(struct("*"))) \
   .withColumn("id", lit(id))
df = df.select('json_content', 'id')
df = df.withColumn('json_content', regexp_replace(col('json_content'), "'", "`"))

df.repartition(12).write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", url) \
            .option("dbtable", f"{schema}.{table_name}") \
            .option("user", username) \
            .option("password", password) \
            .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
            .option("batchsize", 2000000, ) \
            .option("stringtype", "unspecified") \
            .mode("append") \
            .save()
```

All setting are default settings. I can see the data load from s3 happens fast but after that it fails with OOM:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 7
```

Based on my code and cluster size what should be the driver memory, executor memory and the other configuration number?

few error logs:

```
023-02-21 20:49:43,218 ERROR [dispatcher-event-loop-5] scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl (Logging.scala:logError(70)): Lost executor 1 on 10.121.79.169: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

My assumption, because of repartition(12) driver will be involved and driver is not able to handle that.I am all using using default driver and executor memory and default number of executor and core settings.

Comment: Try to re-partition exactly after `load`, I think also you can try more partitions since you have 3 workers and 8 vcpu so maybe you could repartition to `24`

Comment: can you add your submit details?

Comment: I ran it from aws glue job, didnt add any conf parameter

Comment: In the log I can see this `/usr/bin/java -cp /tmp:/opt/amazon/conf:/opt/amazon/glue-manifest.jar com.amazonaws.services.glue.PrepareLaunch --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=2 --conf spark.executor.memory=20g --conf spark.executor.cores=16 --conf spark.driver.memory=20g --conf spark.default.parallelism=48 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=48 --conf spark.network.timeout=600`